# how to get text in xml tag in sax parsing

Tags: c++, sax, xerces

i am using xerces 3 in my c++  program .
i would like some one to guide me , how to extract text between start and end tag in sax parsing .
for example , suppose we have :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="123">
      <author>Introduction to algorithm </author>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

how to access this text : 'Introduction to algorithm'

Comment: Show us what you have so far (simple, not a huge program), it may be something simple to add.

Comment: my question is really simple ! I want to read text between xml tag

Comment: If it was really simple you'ld be able to do it yourself... I'm writing up some vague ideas as an answer, but I can't give any example code without a starting point (i.e. I'm not going to write an entire program for you).

Comment: i think it's better to some one else answer me ! some one who have some experience about xerces sax parsing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you write your own handler inheriting from `HandlerBase`. `startElement()` will be called at `<author>` and then `endElement()` will be called at `</author>`. All text in between will be passed to `characters()`, so you need to know when you are inside `<author></author>`, and make use of this to save the characters to a useful place inside your `characters()` function: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classHandlerBase.html

When I did this (some time ago) I just cheated and had everything as attributes, which are passed in to `startElement()` and saves a lot of hassle.

EDIT: I made my own example and had the same problem (which you didn't describe well in the question, and would have been easier to work out if you'ld provided your code, by the way).
Look at the [documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classHandlerBase.html) (note I wasn't careful about checking which version, but still):

```
virtual void characters (const XMLCh *const chars, const XMLSize_t length)
```

Then check the actual header file.

```
virtual void characters
(
    const   XMLCh* const    chars
    , const unsigned int    length
);
```

Spot the difference? Make your own version's signature match the header file, it will work.

Comment: yes that is correct , we should use characters() method ! but my character method never be called in parsing

Comment: should i register something about it ?

Comment: @paradisalprogrammer Don't know if you are still looking here, but I put together my own example, and worked out why my `characters()` function wasn't being called. Adding an update to my answer now.

Comment: with special thanks to BoBTFish ! bad signature was the main problem

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
void HandlerBase::characters    (   const XMLCh *const      chars,
    const XMLSize_t     length   
)
```

Just be aware that this might be called numerous times.

Comment: It's not very clear from the question, but I think (s?)he tried that, and it was never called. That's also what happened for me, until I realised that the signature in the documentation is not quite the same as that in the header, so I wasn't overriding the default (empty) implementation.

Comment: C++11 now includes the override keyword, using it can save you the heartache of not overriding the correct function.

Answer (score -1):

Use the override keyword at your methods. This might help you a little bit